# glassfish won't deploy with database

Tags: java, mysql, netbeans, jdbc, glassfish-4

is supposed to connect to a phpmyadmin database on an easyphp server insert a record on the users database and all of this goes through web services via glassfish server but this isn't happening

netbeans says that glassfish is running because it only has an option to stop, remove or restart the server but the 'start' option is greyed out

```
package Java;

import javax.jws.WebService;
import java.sql.ResultSet;
import java.sql.Statement;
import java.sql.Connection;
import java.sql.PreparedStatement;
import java.sql.DriverManager;
/**
 *
 * @author Laplet Repair
 */
@WebService(serviceName = "AddUser")

public class AddUser {
    private Statement statement = null;
    private PreparedStatement preparedStatement = null;
    private ResultSet resultSet = null;
    private Connection connect = null;

     public void readDataBase() throws Exception {
    try {
      // This will load the MySQL driver, each DB has its own driver
      Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");
      // Setup the connection with the DB
      connect = DriverManager
          .getConnection("jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/conquest_of_the_fates_user?zeroDateTimeBehavior=convertToNull"
              + "user=root&password=");

      // Statements allow to issue SQL queries to the database
      statement = connect.createStatement();

      // PreparedStatements can use variables and are more efficient
      preparedStatement = connect
          .prepareStatement("insert into  feedback.comments values (default, ?, ?, ?)");
      // "myuser, webpage, datum, summery, COMMENTS from feedback.comments");
      // Parameters start with 1
      preparedStatement.setString(1, "username");
      preparedStatement.setInt(2, 5);
      preparedStatement.setString(3, "password");
      preparedStatement.executeUpdate();

      resultSet = statement
      .executeQuery("select * from feedback.comments");      
    } catch (Exception e) {
      throw e;
    } finally {
      close();
    }

  }

  // You need to close the resultSet
  private void close() {
    try {
      if (resultSet != null) {
        resultSet.close();
      }

      if (statement != null) {
        statement.close();
      }

      if (connect != null) {
        connect.close();
      }
    } catch (Exception e) {

    }
  }
}
```

this is the error log

> java.lang.RuntimeException: java.io.IOException   at
>   com.sun.enterprise.v3.admin.AdminAdapter.onMissingResource(AdminAdapter.java:266)
>     at
>   org.glassfish.grizzly.http.server.StaticHttpHandlerBase.service(StaticHttpHandlerBase.java:189)
>     at
>   com.sun.enterprise.v3.services.impl.ContainerMapper$HttpHandlerCallable.call(ContainerMapper.java:459)
>     at
>   com.sun.enterprise.v3.services.impl.ContainerMapper.service(ContainerMapper.java:167)
>     at
>   org.glassfish.grizzly.http.server.HttpHandler.runService(HttpHandler.java:201)
>     at
>   org.glassfish.grizzly.http.server.HttpHandler.doHandle(HttpHandler.java:175)
>     at
>   org.glassfish.grizzly.http.server.HttpServerFilter.handleRead(HttpServerFilter.java:235)
>     at
>   org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.ExecutorResolver$9.execute(ExecutorResolver.java:119)
>     at
>   org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.DefaultFilterChain.executeFilter(DefaultFilterChain.java:284)
>     at
>   org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.DefaultFilterChain.executeChainPart(DefaultFilterChain.java:201)
>     at
>   org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.DefaultFilterChain.execute(DefaultFilterChain.java:133)
>     at
>   org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.DefaultFilterChain.process(DefaultFilterChain.java:112)
>     at
>   org.glassfish.grizzly.ProcessorExecutor.execute(ProcessorExecutor.java:77)
>     at
>   org.glassfish.grizzly.nio.transport.TCPNIOTransport.fireIOEvent(TCPNIOTransport.java:561)
>     at
>   org.glassfish.grizzly.strategies.AbstractIOStrategy.fireIOEvent(AbstractIOStrategy.java:112)
>     at
>   org.glassfish.grizzly.strategies.WorkerThreadIOStrategy.run0(WorkerThreadIOStrategy.java:117)
>     at
>   org.glassfish.grizzly.strategies.WorkerThreadIOStrategy.access$100(WorkerThreadIOStrategy.java:56)
>     at
>   org.glassfish.grizzly.strategies.WorkerThreadIOStrategy$WorkerThreadRunnable.run(WorkerThreadIOStrategy.java:137)
>     at
>   org.glassfish.grizzly.threadpool.AbstractThreadPool$Worker.doWork(AbstractThreadPool.java:565)
>     at
>   org.glassfish.grizzly.threadpool.AbstractThreadPool$Worker.run(AbstractThreadPool.java:545)

Answer (score 0):

You should configure on glassfish admin console a "JDBC Resource"+"JDBC Connection pool" to your MySQL data base
[How to setup a JDBC connection in Glassfish](https://computingat40s.wordpress.com/how-to-setup-a-jdbc-connection-in-glassfish/)

*You may need to deploy a MySQL jdbc implementation library in:
glassfish-install-path\domains\domain-name\lib*

And create a EJB Singleton to  retrieve connections:

```
@Singleton
@LocalBean
public class DBConnections {

    @Resource(lookup = "resource JNDI name")
    private DataSource dataSource;

    public Connection getConnection() throws SQLException {
        return dataSource.getConnection();
    }
}
```